# Firebase 9.0.0 Google Auth not working with Note 4 (SM-910F) 6.0.1

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have checkout the Firebase-Auth demo projct for Android [(link)](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android).
I set it up with the google-services.json. It runs on the emulator, on the S3(4.3)/S3(mini)(4.2) and A3(5.0.1). But it get an auth error on my Note 4 (6.0.1).

I get a token from google play services. But the task in `#firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount acct)` never successful.

Can anyone confirm this? Or have someone an idear how to fix this?

```
package de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app.persistence.firebase;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;


/**
 * Created by Dagobert on 23.05.2016.
 */
public class FireLoginHelper implements          GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = FireLoginHelper.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 12345;
private final AppCompatActivity activity;
private final FirebaseApplication application;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

public class FireLoginHelper implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = FireLoginHelper.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 12345;
private final AppCompatActivity activity;
private final FirebaseApplication application;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

public FireLoginHelper(final AppCompatActivity activity, FirebaseApplication application) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.application = application;
}

public void onCreate() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(activity.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .enableAutoManage(activity, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    signIn();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            application.userChanged();
        }
    };
}

public void onStart() {
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

public void onStop() {
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        final GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            final GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            //TODO Fehlerbehandlung verbesser
            Log.e(TAG, "Google auth fail");
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.e(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle() " + acct.getIdToken());
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //TODO Fehlerbehandlung verbessern
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Auth complete");
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed() " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
}
}
```

I got thes exception back:

```
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app     W/System.err: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: API: InternalFirebaseAuth.FIREBASE_AUTH_API is not available on this device.
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznp$zzb.zzv(Unknown Source)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoj$zzc.zzz(Unknown Source)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoj$zzc.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoj$zzd.zzh(Unknown Source)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzk.zzl(Unknown Source)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zze.zztr(Unknown Source)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
05-25 17:25:36.221 3434-3434/de.dokate.dagobert.foodchecker.android.app W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

regards Dagobert

Comment: updation issues may be your google play services is outdated

Comment: Google Play Services is on version 9.0.83

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you're not the only one. I have a similar issue, and apparently someone also complained about it on GitHub.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/18